# Jetpack Joyride user movement

Tags: java, if-statement

i am trying to create a game similar to jetpack joyride in which the user can hold the spacebar to go up and let go to travel downward. I am using timers to simulate the gravity and using `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` to check if the user is holding the spacebar. I am using print statements to know for sure that both keyPressed and keyReleased are working, but i dont know why the physics arent running. I dont know whether the problem is my if statements not updating, if it is the new timers being created inside of the if statement. Either way, the gravity is not changing, and im stuck. Help is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Calendar;



public class Game implements KeyListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel player;

    public boolean grounded = false;
    public int velocity = 0;
    public int finalY = 0;
    public boolean spaceHeld = false;


    Action spaceAction;

    Game() {
         
        frame = new JFrame("Nicholas Seow-Xi Crouse");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);

        player = new JLabel();
        player.setBackground(Color.red);
        player.setBounds(10, 1800, 50, 50);
        player.setOpaque(true);

        frame.add(player);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
         Timer flightTime = new Timer();
         TimerTask flight = new TimerTask() {
         
            public void run() {
                  if(velocity > -5) {
                  velocity -= 1;
                  }
                  else{
                  velocity = -5;
                  }
                  if (finalY < -61) {
                   finalY = finalY + velocity;
                   }
                   else{
                   finalY = -61;
                   }
                   player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                   if (player.getY() <= 0){
                   cancel();
                   velocity = 0;
                   finalY = 0;
                   player.setLocation(player.getX(), 0);
                    
                   }  
            }
      };
         

         Timer gravityTime = new Timer();
         TimerTask gravity = new TimerTask() {


            //creates a timer run method that simulates the falling gravity when not grounded
            public void run() {
                if(velocity < 5){
                velocity += 1;
                }
                else{
                velocity = 5;
                }
                //creates the variable the tells where the player is located
                if (finalY < 61) {
                finalY = finalY + velocity;
                }
                else{
                finalY = 61;
                }
                player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                if (player.getY() >= 1000){
                cancel();
                velocity = 0;
                finalY = 0;
                player.setLocation(player.getX(), 990); 
                }
                
            }
        };

        if (spaceHeld == false ) {
            gravityTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(gravity, 0, 33);
        }
        if (spaceHeld == true ) {
            flightTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(flight, 0 ,33);
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
spaceHeld = true;
//debug
System.out.println(spaceHeld);
}
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
spaceHeld = false;
//debug
System.out.println(spaceHeld);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is event based, and currently nothing triggers your timers to start. To do this you can simply move the timer schedule/start actions inside the key events:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){

            //Cancel the other timer here so that they don't overlap
            gravity.cancel();
            gravityTime.cancel();

            //Create a new instance of the timer
            flightTime = new Timer();
            flight = new TimerTask() {
     
                public void run() {
                    if(velocity > -5) {
                        velocity -= 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        velocity = -5;
                    }
                    if (finalY < -61) {
                        finalY = finalY + velocity;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalY = -61;
                    }

                    player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                    if (player.getY() <= 0){
                        cancel();
                        velocity = 0;
                        finalY = 0;
                        player.setLocation(player.getX(), 0);
                    }  
                }
            };

            //Now start the timer
            flightTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(flight, 0 ,33);
        }
    }
    
    //Do the same for the gravity method
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){

            ......

        }
    }
}
```

Note above that you should also cancel the other scheduled task with the opposing key events so that they do not overlap each other and value strange results.

And to make `flightTime` and `gravityTime` accessible to the keyPressed method simply declare them as class variables:

```
public class Game implements KeyListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel player;

    public boolean grounded = false;
    public int velocity = 0;
    public int finalY = 0;
    public boolean spaceHeld = false;

    //Move them here but don't assign a value:
    public Timer flightTime;
    public TimerTask flight;
    public Timer gravityTime;
    public TimerTask gravity;
```

You can still create the object later in the Game method:

```
flightTime = new Timer();
flight = new TimerTask() {
    ....
};
```

Comment: Hello, this method had worked for me, although i am getting an exception saying that the gravity task is already scheduled. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZZBowzer Make sure that it is being cancelled first `gravity.cancel();` before trying to run it again, or if the task is already running then there is no need to start it again just let it run?

Comment: You could also move the timer creation inside the KeyPressed method (see my edited code above), but this may still create issues with timers overlapping if they are not stopped correctly. It would honestly be better to use a single timer/task to control the animation that never needs to be cancelled/started, and just have it read a boolean to see if it should move up or down.